# what does the expression $\frac{2}{53} + \frac{7}{53}i$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone tell me what, what i presume is a variable $i$, represents in the expression $(2-7i)^{-1}$ and how it supposedly equates $\dfrac{2}{53} + \dfrac{7}{53}i$

Comment: $i$ is the imaginary unit. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

Comment: An appropriate answer here very much depends on what you know about complex numbers already. If you've never heard of them, it's one thing. If you've heard and you already know that this is about them, but still cannot understand how one is the inverse of each other - it's a different matter.

Comment: This is a way to find the equation you mention: $\frac{1}{2-7i}=\frac{1}{2-7i}\times\frac{2+7i}{2+7i}=\frac{2+7i}{2^{2}-\left(7i\right)^{2}}=\frac{2+7i}{4-\left(-49\right)}=\frac{2}{53}+\frac{7}{53}i$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming: $i=\sqrt{-1}$, you have:$(2-7i)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2-7i}$. 
Multiplying the denominator for the complex conjugate ($2+7i$), you get:
$$\frac{2+7i}{53}=\frac{2}{53}+\frac{7i}{53}$$